# Can I charge my laptop using a simple USB cigarette lighter

Tags: charging, computer

I’m not sure this is the same thing as the 100w inverter i saw mentioned in another answer. This is supposed to work for phones but I’ve never used it for my laptop as I’m afraid it’ll break it.

It’s an Anker power drive 2, says on it Input: 12/24V -> 3A. Output: 5.0V -> 4.8A.

My car is an old 2005 Mazda

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peak power of your little USB charger is 5*12=60 Watts, and it will get very hot with that. In theory, if your laptop charger's power rating is below that, you may be able to pull this off, but I wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Do you think a 100W inverter 12VDC to 110VAC as was mentioned somewhere else would work?

Comment: absolutely see answer below

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 100 watt inverter will easily charge your laptop. If your laptop draws less than 100 watts not only can you charge it, you can also use it in your car when you are stopped at a rest area. Net surfing not reccommended while driving the police will get after you for that :) .

The DC power connection on the laptop is usually about 19 V @ 3.42A (Asus model laptop 65 watts) The 5 V usb device wouldn't work unless you had a device to boost both the voltage and current to what the laptop needs to function. The inverter would just plug into the car's 12 V and then you plug in the laptop adapter plug into the inverter and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say "you can also use it in your car when you are stopped at a rest area", wouldn't this kill the car's battery?

Comment: Depends how long you use it. The laptop uses roughly about the same power as your headlights or car stereo. Your laptop also has a rechargeable battery to give about 2or more hours of surf time.